# three20 TTTextBarController semantic error ios 6

Tags: ios, three20

I'm having semantic issues with TTTextBarController.m

The error relates to 2 lines. Both of which relate read:

```
Property 'viewController' not found on object of type UIView *
```

Happening on these lines

```
 - (void)textEditorDidEndEditing:(TTTextEditor*)textEditor {
  UIViewController* controller = self.view.viewController;
  [controller.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:_previousRightBarButtonItem animated:YES];
  TT_RELEASE_SAFELY(_previousRightBarButtonItem);
```

and here:

```
    (void)textEditorDidBeginEditing:(TTTextEditor*)textEditor {
  [self retain];

  _originTop = self.view.top;

  UIViewController* controller = self.view.viewController;
  _previousRightBarButtonItem = [controller.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem retain];
```

How do I resolve this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not the answer you're looking for, but you really should think of stop using three20. It's a very old library, and [it's been officially discontinued](https://github.com/facebook/three20).

Comment: Yeah I know. I just inherited a project that was using it. I'm trying to get it to work so that I can change what we're using.